# Postman Icon missing on Ubuntu14.04 sidebar launcher after version update

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, postman

I have updated the native postman version from 5.2.0 to 6.2.5 in my Ubuntu 14.04 system and all my previous version API collections are available without any issues.

When I tried to lock Postman to the sidebar Launcher on my Ubuntu system, I noticed the Postman icon is not displaying and it is displaying **?** symbol instead. I have restarted the Postman application as well but no luck. Anyone solved this problem before or can I safely ignore this since there is no issues with Postman functional features?

[image]

Comment: I don't suppose this would have any functional impact, Did you try making few calls from postman ? If all works fine - you can ignore this

Comment: hi @WilfredClement, yes I did few API calls after updated the version and it is working fine so far